# Display error messages on the edit password page for registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I've followed Devise's wiki on ["How to allow users to edit their password (Solution 3)"](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password). However, the default view code provided in the wiki does not display error messages if the password does not meet certain requirements (say 6 chars instead of 8). I've thus added the following line: `-if devise_error_messages? = devise_error_messages!` into the form:

```
= form_for(@user, :url => { action: "update_password" } ) do |f|
  -if devise_error_messages?
    = devise_error_messages!
  .field
    = f.label :current_password
    = f.password_field :current_password
  .field
    = f.label :password, "Password"
    = f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"
  .field
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  .action_container
    = f.submit
```

This however returns an error `undefined local variable or method 'resource' for #<#<Class:0x007f974d2b8ae0>:0x007f974d3f8888>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line solved the issue:

```
-if not @user.errors.empty?
   = @user.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| msg }.join
```